# Ошибка в нумерации при обращении через nth-of-type

Tags: html, css

У меня есть 3 div'a c классом request-form-input-block.

```
<div class="request-form-input-block">
    <label class="label request-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <input class="input request-input" type="text" placeholder="What is your name:" id="name">
</div>
<div class="request-form-input-block">
    <label class="label request-label" for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input class="input request-input" type="text" placeholder="Your phone number:" id="phone">
</div>
<div class="request-form-input-block">
    <label class="label request-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <input class="input request-input" type="text" placeholder="Your email:" id="email">
</div>
```

Мне нужно установить дополнительные стили ко 2му div'у. Но почему то по селктору .request-form-input-block:nth-of-type(2) стили добавляются к 1му div'у. Почему это может происходить? Я проверял через поиск по файлу, у меня больше нет элементов с классом request-form-input-block

Answer (score 0):

> Но почему то по селктору .request-form-input-block:nth-of-type(2) стили добавляются к 1му div'у.

Все применяется ко второму `div`...

```css
 .request-form-input-block:nth-of-type(2) {
  border: 1px solid;
 }
```

```html
<div class="request-form-input-block">
  <label class="label request-label" for="name">Name</label>
  <input class="input request-input" type="text" placeholder="What is your name:" id="name">
</div>
<div class="request-form-input-block">
  <label class="label request-label" for="phone">Phone</label>
  <input class="input request-input" type="text" placeholder="Your phone number:" id="phone">
</div>
<div class="request-form-input-block">
  <label class="label request-label" for="email">Email</label>
  <input class="input request-input" type="text" placeholder="Your email:" id="email">
</div>
```